# Can't resolve 'angularfire2' - Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire2, angular

I was creating a Angular 4 project with Angularfire2 and firebase using this guide:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

When I installed everything and I try to run "ng serve" the following error apears:

ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'angularfire2' in '......'

I saw more people with this problem, but I those answers didn't help me.

I am using Angular 4, and my package.json looks like this:

```
{
"name": "xxxxxxx",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"ng": "ng",
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
"test": "ng test",
"lint": "ng lint",
"e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/common": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/core": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/http": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/platform-server": "^4.0.1",
"@angular/router": "^4.0.1",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"rxjs": "^5.1.0",
"typescript": "^2.2.2",
"zone.js": "^0.8.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular/cli": "1.0.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
"@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
"@types/node": "~6.0.60",
"codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
"karma": "~1.4.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
"protractor": "~5.1.0",
"ts-node": "~2.0.0",
"tslint": "~4.5.0",
"typescript": "~2.2.0"
}
}
```

Does anybody sees why this error appears and how I can resolve it?

Comment: `angularfire2` is nowhere to be seen in your `package.json`, so that's likely part of the problem. At least install it: `npm install angularfire2 --save`

Comment: I did run that install. But angularfire2 doesn't show up in the package.json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is was because Firebase itself wasn't installed right.
This did it for me:

npm install firebase angularfire2 --save